# Not showing an echo message

Tags: php

I am unsure why I am not getting an echo if it is a prime number

```
$numPrime = 2;

function Number($numPrime)
{
    for($numPrime = 0; $numPrime < 100; $numPrime++)
    {
        if($numPrime == TRUE)
        {
            echo("TRUE");
        }else{
            echo("FALSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$numPrime` actually being set true/false?

Comment: where's your function name..?

Comment: have you tried putting an echo statement inside the function call but outside the `for` loop?

Comment: Think everyone is neglecting the fact his if statement is looking for a true or false. Nothing is put in place to give $numprime a true or false value..

Comment: @Patrick nope so it means my loops not working

Comment: @DarylGill Also the fact that the function is never called. And that the argument is overwritten by the for loop.

Comment: @DarylGill: The double equals sign coerces `$numPrime` to a boolean, so `5 == TRUE`.

Comment: @Blender every single number in that loop, with the exception of 0 is going to echo true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this

```
for($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++) {
    if($num % $i == 0) {
        echo "false";
    }
}
echo "true";
```

Comment: Can you explain the `%`.  How would I do if it is Prime return TRUE else false and then run the function

Comment: @JessMcKenzie The `%` ([modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)) does division and returns the remainder (if it exists) from the quotient.  If the remainder is 0 then the number is a factor of the other number and therefore isn't a prime number

Comment: @Patrick thanks I seem to be getting a blank page when I run echo $Number;